# Bootstrap 5 Image responsiveness

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, frontend, bootstrap-5

1

I am using Bootstrap 5 to create a website and in my feature and mission sections I want the images to move above the text when the viewport is mobile or tablet size, but I am not sure how to accomplish this. For example, on one page of my site, I did this to achieve the same functionality mentioned above:

```html
<div class="col-md col-12 order-1 order-md-0">
      <h3 class="display-3 text-start" pt-5>General Support</h3>
      <br>
      <!-- <br> -->
      <p class="text-start">
        Sit nisi ipsum sint incididunt qui amet cupidatat quis qui adipisicing excepteur ea consequat consequat. Anim qui non ex labore enim non Lorem. Sint sint consectetur magna quis proident anim. Ipsum dolor voluptate do veniam exercitation mollit quis adipisicing commodo labore voluptate cupidatat aliquip. Sint sit culpa nostrud laboris voluptate Lorem cupidatat.
        <br />
        <br />
        Proident deserunt nulla aliquip sint dolor. Labore qui quis cillum deserunt voluptate et nostrud et elit reprehenderit. Deserunt aliqua sint esse elit proident do excepteur proident anim. Adipisicing magna magna ullamco do ea in consectetur aliqua aliquip sint excepteur ex. Reprehenderit magna officia adipisicing exercitation qui sint amet fugiat et ipsum amet velit consectetur commodo. Eu duis laboris eiusmod ad quis ut voluptate. Nisi amet quis do laborum occaecat non mollit sunt.
        <br />
        <br />
        Culpa laborum occaecat exercitation deserunt nulla laboris est. Aliqua culpa et qui non mollit cupidatat excepteur. Labore ea ipsum sit est ipsum commodo velit adipisicing culpa aute et nostrud laboris. In ex velit proident veniam nostrud tempor duis ut sint.
      </p>
      <br />
      <div class="d-grid  col-6 mx-auto mb-4 text-start">
        <a href="./ticket-form">
          <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" id="button">Submit&nbsp;a&nbsp;Ticket</button>
        </a>
          
        </div>
      </div>
```

However when I try to do the same thing now I can't get it to work.

This is the code snippet of the code I am trying to add this functionality to:

```html
<!-- FEATURE SECTION START -->
    <section>
      <div class="container">
        <div class="row bg-white  mt-1 px-2">
          <div class="col-lg-6 col-sm-12 order-sm-1">
            <img src="./src/img/feature-section.jpeg" alt=" logo" class=" img-fluid rounded float-start mb-2 img-fluid mt-1" id="#team-img"/>
          </div>
          <div class="col-lg-6 col-sm-12 order-sm-2">
            <h2 class="display-6" id="about-heading">About Us</h2>
            <hr>
            <p class="lead mt-5">
              Ullamco nostrud ipsum laboris sint commodo. Do duis veniam culpa tempor veniam laboris dolor amet minim qui incididunt ipsum. Magna proident commodo ea do eiusmod amet cupidatat eu do commodo consectetur Lorem dolore exercitation. Tempor tempor id consectetur in exercitation enim reprehenderit amet elit ullamco veniam adipisicing officia eu. Cupidatat non velit in aliquip exercitation eiusmod occaecat aliqua ex.
            </p>
            <a href="./about#about" class="btn btn-primary mt-3" id="button">Read&nbsp;More</a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>
    <!-- FEATURE SECTION CLOSE -->

    <!-- MISSION SECTION START -->
    <section>
      <div class="container">
        <div class="row bg-white pt-5 px-2">
          <div class="col-lg-6 col-sm-12 order-sm-2">
            <h2 class="display-6" id="mission-heading">Our Mission</h2>
            <hr>
            <p class="lead mt-5">
              Ullamco nostrud ipsum laboris sint commodo. Do duis veniam culpa tempor veniam laboris dolor amet minim qui incididunt ipsum. Magna proident commodo ea do eiusmod amet cupidatat eu do commodo consectetur Lorem dolore exercitation. Tempor tempor id consectetur in exercitation enim reprehenderit amet elit ullamco veniam adipisicing officia eu. Cupidatat non velit in aliquip exercitation eiusmod occaecat aliqua ex.
            </p>
            <a href="./about#mission" class="btn btn-primary mt-3 mb-3" id="button">Read&nbsp;More</a>
          </div>
          <div class="col-lg-6 col-sm-12 order-sm-first">
            
            <img src="./src/img/team-section002.jpeg" alt=" logo" class="img-fluid mb-2 img-fluid rounded float-start" id="#team-img"/>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>
    <!-- MISSION SECTION CLOSE -->
```

Answer (score 0):

I looked at your code in a bootstrapped sandbox locally and it looks good. I don't have access to your CSS. If you could provide that, I may be able to create a codepen.

As per your question - the images reposition as you requested. They move above the text (within the container/row --> your columns are working properly). If you don't see this working properly on your end, check the bootstrap call - it should look something like this:

```
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">
```

Please provide CSS or, if this helped, let us know - best of luck.

Comment: it didn't work but i found the syntax was wrong I was supposed to be using `order-0 order-sm-1` and `order-1 order-sm-0`